# UnauthorizedAccessException c#

Tags: c#, directory, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Im getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when I try to write files to a newly created folder. It should create a writable folder.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 //creating folder
uploadDirectory = directoryBox.Text + "\\Uploads";
 if (!Directory.Exists(uploadDirectory))
    {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDirectory);
    }
//writing file to folder
File.WriteAllBytes(uploadDirectory, file);
```

The file is a bytefile. How can I make the folder writable?

Comment: Do you require administrator rights to write in that directory? If so, are you running your application with those rights?

Comment: Or more generally... does the user account running the app have permission to write to the folder, at the file system level (often it's admin vs non-admin, but not always).

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to write to the upload directory. You should be writing to a file. So really your code should be

```
File.WriteAllBytes(uploadDirectory + "\\" + fileName, file)
```

You might also have to add permissions to the folder.

```
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(uploadDirectory);
        if (!directoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDirectory);
        }

        var sec = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
        var accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);

        sec.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
        directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(sec);
```

This should be done before attempting to write to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the instant help this is the solution for my problem